# My Chrome addon for removing Youtube autoplay breaks posting on forums

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a Chrome addon that removes the autoplay from embedded Youtube videos. However, when I try to post on a forum that has a minimum character limit for posts, I get an error about my post not being long enough. That occurs only when my addon is active. Here is my codes:

manifest.json:

```
{
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "js": [ "js/replace.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*" ],
      "run_at": "document_idle"
   } ],
   "description": "some text",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "No autoplay",
   "permissions": [ "tabs", "http://*/*" ],
   "version": "1.0"
}
```

replace.js:

```
var str1 = '&autoplay=1', str2 = '?autoplay=1', empty = '', regex1 = /\\&autoplay=1/gi, regex1 = /\\?autoplay=1/gi;
var ind = document.body.innerHTML.indexOf(str1);
while (ind != -1) {
    console.log("replacing");
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(regex1, empty);
    ind = document.body.innerHTML.indexOf(str1);
}
ind = document.body.innerHTML.indexOf(str2);
while (ind != -1) {
    console.log("replacing");
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(regex2, empty);
    ind = document.body.innerHTML.indexOf(str2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a link contains `str2`, you are deleting `?` character. That means, all other $_GET parameters are being moved to url section.

For example:

`someurl.com?autoplay=1&movie_id=10` turns into `someurl.com&movie_id=10` ... and it is invalid, because it should be `someurl.com?movie_id=10`...

Safer way would be replacing `autoplay=1` with `autoplay=0`.